# Regarding Ubuntu installation on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: installation

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 (desktop i386) on my HP laptop which already has Windows 7 installed on it. I have an Ubuntu setup file as ISO file in my USB.

My question is, if I install Ubuntu through USB or by copying it on Windows 7 and then installing Ubuntu, will any of the data stored in my hard disk is lost?... because I have 200GB of data which I don't want to lose. I want both Windows 7 and Ubuntu to run on my same laptop. Is this possible?

My laptop Configuration:
    HP Pavilion g series
    RAM - 4GB
    Windows 7 OS - 64-BIT
    IntelL Core i3 2330M CPU, 2.20GHz

Thanks for your quote. Well, my laptop hard disk capacity is 500GB, and currently my hard disk is holding around 275GB of data. Well, it's almost more than half.  So I think Ubuntu needs 20GB of free space. Now the thing is that I am having only one drive which is C drive, it's holding around 275GB of data, which includes the Windows setup, all other software installations, and also my personal important data which is around 92GB. All this is only in the C drive. I have two more drives which are of 15GB and 4GB. One is the recovery drive (D drive) and the other one is HP_Tools drive (E drive).

Is it possible to make one more drive so that I will install Ubuntu on that drive? I mean is it possible to shrink it?

Comment: Dual-booting is possible without loosing any data. During the process your hard drive partitions will be resized, in theory this can go wrong and corrupt data (very rare) so it is a good idea to back up vital data. It is a good idea to back it up even if you aren't installing operating systems and playing with partitions!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is completely possible. I am using both OS parallelly and I am not having any problem at all. My PC configuration is slightly better though. But I doubt it has anything to do with dual boot. Your laptop will run one OS at a time (so, chill). The only thing matters is, do you have enough hard disk space?
Now, due to the new partition you create to install Ubuntu, no stored data should be lost. The space you allocate to Ubuntu, will simply come from the free spaces available in HDD. No existing data will be touched. I also have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Win7 and after nearly a year now, it is still running smoothly and I haven't got any data missing.

Personal opinion: Keeping in mind the future, allocate some good amount of space (like 100GB at least) in you Ubuntu.